# ASP.NET MVC: ActionFilterAttribute not setting ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, viewdata, actionfilterattribute

I've written the following ActionFilterAttribute

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Namespace Mvc.Filters
    Public Class StopWatchFilter : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
        Private tStart As DateTime
        Private tStop As DateTime

        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting( _
            ByVal filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)

            tStart = DateTime.Now

        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub OnResultExecuted( _
            ByVal filterContext As ResultExecutedContext)

            tStop = DateTime.Now
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData("StopWatch") = _
                ((tStop - tStart).TotalMilliseconds / 1000).ToString(".00")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I set in on my controller

```
''# Fixes SO code coloring
<MyApp.StopWatch()>
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

But then when I try to display the `ViewData("StopWatch")` in my View, it's just blank.

I'm I missing something stupid here?

#### EDIT:

It appears as though I can set the `ViewData` in the `OnActinExecuting` but **not** in the `OnResultExecuted`.

So, how on earth might I be able to build a stopwatch `ActionFilter`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Write the total execution time of a request to the response?  If so, then you're at a catch-22, because you won't know the execution time until the request has finished processing, but at that time, the response has already been determined/written.  If you are sticking with MVC closely (very little to no logic in the view), then timing the action will get you very close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it.

`OnActionExecuted` allows me to still write results to the view because the results haven't been executed yet (where `OnResultExecuted` has already executed the results to the view)!

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Namespace Mvc.Filters
    Public Class StopWatchFilter : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
        Private tStart As DateTime
        Private tStop As DateTime

        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
            tStart = DateTime.Now
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(ByVal filterContext As ActionExecutedContext)
            tStop = DateTime.Now
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData("StopWatch") = ((tStop - tStart).TotalMilliseconds / 1000).ToString(".00")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Basically, if you attach the above Attribute to any action, and use `ViewData("StopWatch")` in your view. You can see how long it took for the Controller Action to execute.

Comment: What does "better" mean? They're just different events so just different hooks through MVC execution pipeline.